# How can we filter subquery in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

The query I am using is

```
select count(*) as count,
       TO_CHAR(firstTable1.firstTable_date, 'DD-MON-YY') as  dateAndTime
from  (
  select *
  from   firstTable
  where  firstTable_status = 'Open'
  and    firstTable_date   > sysdate-10
) firstTable1
group by TO_CHAR(firstTable1.firstTable_date, 'DD-MON-YY')
```

which will give me count 1 on 11-may-17

and count 1 for 09-may-17

sample table data is

firstTable

```
                    id        firstTable_status  firstTable_date

                   A-123         Open                11-may-17
                   B-123         Open                09-may-17
```

secondTable

```
  secondTable_Id    firstTable_id      secondTable_Action  secondTable_date

       XX1       A-123            started                 11-may-17
       XX2       A-123            Assigned                11-may-17
       XX3       A-123            action2                 11-may-17
       XX4       A-123            action3                 11-may-17
       XX5       A-123            action4                 11-may-17
       XX6       A-123            action5                 11-may-17
       XX7       A-123            closed                  11-may-17

       MN1       B-123            started                09-may-17
       MN1       B-123            action1                10-may-17
       MN1       B-123            closed                 11-may-17
```

is it possible to modify this query such as

if the secondTable_Action is closed for same id on same date then then query should not return count for that id

for example  id A-123 in firstTable is open on 11-may-17 and closed on same 
    day whose entry in second table for this query should return count 0  for 11-
    may-17
    while for id B-123 is closed on different day so for this it should return 
    count 1 on 09-may-17

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dt,
       SUM( open_closed ) AS "count"
FROM   (
  SELECT f.id,
         TRUNC( f.firstTable_date ) as dt,
         COUNT( CASE s.secondtable_action WHEN 'started' THEN 1 END )
           - COUNT( CASE s.secondtable_action WHEN 'closed' THEN 1 END ) AS open_closed
  FROM   firstTable f
         INNER JOIN secondtable s
         ON ( f.id = s.firsttable_id )
  WHERE  firstTable_date   > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '10' DAY
  GROUP BY f.id,
         TRUNC( f.firstTable_date )
  HAVING COUNT( CASE s.secondtable_action WHEN 'started' THEN 1 END ) > 0
)
GROUP BY dt
```

Comment: COUNT( CASE s.secondtable_action WHEN 'started' THEN 1 END )
           - COUNT( CASE s.secondtable_action WHEN 'closed' THEN 1 END )
I want count if firstTable_status is open - secondTable_Action is closed if both date is same

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the closes using `not exists` or something similar:

```
select count(*) as count,
       to_char(t.firstTable_date, 'DD-MON-YY') as dateAndTime
from firstTable t
where t.firstTable_status = 'Open' and
      t.firstTable_date > sysdate - 10 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from secondTable t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and
                        t2.firstTable_date = t.firstTable_date and
                        t2.firstTable_status = 'Closed'
                 )
group by to_char(t.firstTable_date, 'DD-MON-YY')
order by min(firstTable_date);
```

Notes:

- If `firstTable_date` has a time component, then the correlation clause should take that into account:  `trunc(t2.firstTable_date) = trunc(t.firstTable_date)`.
- You can use `trunc()` instead of `to_char()`.  If you are going to use `to_char()`, I would advise you to use YYYY-MM-DD format.  This is ISO-standard and works in sorts.
- I added an `order by` so the dates will be in order.
- No subquery is necessary.

Comment: the query which i used and the solution you have given returning same output

Comment: @sumit . . . Never mind.  The subquery should reference the second table, not the first.

Comment: sorry i didnt get you

Comment: @sumit . . . The original version used the same table in the subquery and in the outer query.  You have a second table in the question.